# Codeigniter URL question

Tags: php, url, codeigniter, frameworks

Is there any way I can make user URLs? something like

> www.domain.com/username

I know I probably have to use a route system, and I do use this a lot for other URL requests. But the thing is, I need the username to dynamically create the user profile, if it exists. But do I also need to keep my other controller classes in mind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you realize the potential for a user to step all over your other valid routes by creating a matching user name.

You could try routing all requests as usernames, but providing a trigger for your other controllers (and other valid routes):

```
// Route everything to users profile
$route['(:any)'] = 'users/profile/$1';

// Route all requests after "my_trigger" as normal
$route['my_trigger/(:any)'] = '$1';
```

<sub>*** I'm not sure, but you *may* need to append more `/(:any)`s to the trigger routes.</sub>

This would mean that `my_trigger` would have to be an invalid username, but would be the *only* invalid user name.

The idea is that all non-username requests must be preceded with the additional "trigger" segment, otherwise it will be considered a user name. So `/blog` now must be accessed with `/trigger/blog`.

You could of course do the same with the user name instead, but end up with a less pretty url, like `/u/username`, or use a query string like `?u=username`.

Another option is to specifically whitelist segments that should invoke a controller as normal, and blacklist them from the available user names, while routing all other requests through your users controller.

In any case, if the user name doesn't actually exist - you need to respond appropriately, so there is no real need for "dynamic" routes (i.e. creating a route for each and every user).

Comment: You already got this running? I'm curious because I have never actually used this method of routing. This is working? Feel free to simply upvote, uncheck the accept, and leave the question open for a day or two - someone else may have valuable input.

Comment: BTW, try using a regular expression instead of `:any` for the route, makes more sense and will read the slashes instead of discard them.